# QuickBooks Online cannot create Bill object

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

When I used their QBO API explorer to create a Bill, it failed with following message. 
Is this feature not supported by QBO Simple Start?

```
<FaultInfo xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd">
  <Message>We're sorry. This feature is not included in your QuickBooks Online Simple Start subscription. </Message>
  <ErrorCode>BAD_REQUEST</ErrorCode>
  <Cause>-10621</Cause>
</FaultInfo>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bill xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
<Header>
<DocNumber>2004</DocNumber>
<TxnDate>2010-08-06</TxnDate>
<Msg>4 Pens</Msg>
<VendorId>20</VendorId>
<TotalAmt>50</TotalAmt>
</Header>
<Line>
<Desc>Pens</Desc>
<Amount>25</Amount>
<AccountId>76</AccountId>
</Line>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Simple start subscription in QBO does not support it.
Refer this for comparing all features for different subscription types-
http://quickbooks.intuit.com/online/compare/